# I don't like Wolfram Alpha's evaluation of an integral

Tags: calculus

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%7Csinx%7C) says that $\int|\sin(x)| = -\cos(x)\mathrm{sgn}(\sin(x))$

It cannot be true, since $|\sin(x)|$ is always positive and its integral must grow indefinitely.

But when it comes to calculating the definite integral over intervals the page is right.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the $+C$.

The $+C$ is even more important than usual here; $C$ is only ever required to be *locally constant*. While usually that means it *actually is* constant, the antiderivative that Wolfram Alpha computed is not defined at any of the points $x = n \pi$, where $n$ is an integer

While $C$ must take on the same value across intervals, your domain is made up of many disjoint intervals of the form $(n \pi, (n+1)\pi)$ (where $n$ ranges over all integers), and thus $C$ is allowed to have a different value on each of them.

Technically, the expression WolframAlpha gave is defined everywhere once you've decided what $\operatorname{sgn}(0)$ is, but your function is clearly not differentiable at those points, so it can only be said to be an antiderivative when we exclude the integer multiples of $\pi$.

We can do better than Wolfram Alpha: we can compute an antiderivative that is defined everywhere, by lining up the constants so that the function can be continuously extended to have a value at the integer multiples of $\pi$: the correct antiderivative is

$$ C + \begin{cases} \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1 & \sin(x) = 0
\\ 2 \left\lfloor \frac{x}{\pi} \right\rfloor - \cos(x) \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(x)) 
& \sin(x) \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: +1. You're more generous toward W|A than I would be. :) I would have said it was just wrong at $x = n\pi$, since the antiderivative is not differentiable at those points, no matter how sgn is defined.  Since the integrand is continuous everywhere, there is an antiderivative that is differentiable everywhere, which of course you have given. The W|A antiderivative cannot be used to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which seems a shortcoming worth pointing out.  (W|A and Mathematica often give symbolic results that are only generically correct.)

Comment: FWIW, Your answer can be derived in Mathematica using `Simplify[Integrate[Abs[Sin[t]], {t,0,x}], Assumptions -> x>0]`, but this takes more time than WA typically allows. The actual Alpha result in a slightly different form can be derived via `Integrate[Abs[Sin[t]], t, Assumptions -> Element[t,Reals]]`.

Comment: I just realized that the second theorem of calculus requires the anti derivative to be differentiable everywhere on the interval, that's what the one in the question doesn't exhibit.

Answer (score 0):

Indefinite integrals are functions which, after deriving them, give the original function. Thus, for example, the function $g(x) = x - 100000$ is an indefinite integral of $f(x)=1$, because $g'=f.$

The thing is that if $g$ is an indefinite integral of $f$, then $h(x) = g(x) + C$ is an indefinite integral of $f$ for every $C\in\mathbb R$. Even more, *all* indefinite integrals of $f$ have the form $h(x) = g(x) + C$.

Your second question is now fairly simple. You probably know that if $g'(x) = f(x)$, then $$\int_a^bf(x) dx = g(b) - g(a).$$
Now, if you take any indefinite integral of $f$, say the function $h(x) = g(x) + C$ (for a small enough $C$, this will be a negative function even if $f$ is positive), then $$h(b)-h(a) = g(b) + C - (g(a) + C) = g(b) - g(a).$$

Comment: I know that an indefinite integral is a primitive of a function. With that primitive that Wolfram gave me I cannot properly integrate $|\sin(x)|$ over an interval. In other words I cannot apply the second theorem.